# How do compiled queries in slick actually work?

Tags: scala, slick, compiled-query

I am looking for a detailed explanation about the execution of compiled queries. I can't understand how they just compile once and the advantage behind their use

Comment: Is not that they execute once. It's compiled once.

Comment: Why would they need to be compiled more than once? And are you familiar with prepared statements?

Comment: @perdrofurla yep ! edited... can you give me a clear explanation ?

Comment: Not really, I only have a vague idea. But I summoned the gurus, they might be able to answer effectively.

Comment: actually I am trying to understand a slick example http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/2.1.0/queries.html#compiled-queries and as a beginner i can not understand the advantage behind using compiled queries.

Comment: Non compiled queries takes a lot longer to execute because they need to be translated from Slick structures into actual SQL. In compiled queries, the compilation happens only once, and you reused the result in every execution.

Comment: When you build a query in Slick, it actually builds a data structure that represents you query, or parts of a query, like conditions, joins etc. This structure needs to be compiled into SQL at some point.

Answer (score 18):

Assuming this question is about the usage, not the internal implementation of Compiled queries, here is my answer:

When you write a Slick query, Slick actually creates a data structure internally for all the involved expressions - an abstract syntax tree (AST). When you want to run this query, Slick takes the data structure and translates (or in other words compiles) it into a SQL string. This can be a fairly time intensive process taking more time than actually executing fast SQL queries on the DB. So ideally we shouldn't do this translation to SQL every single time the query needs to be executed. But how to avoid it? By caching the translated/compiled SQL query.

Slick could do something like only compile it the first time and cache it for the next time. But it doesn't, because that makes it harder for the user to reason about Slick's execution time, because the same code will be slow the first time, but faster later. (Also Slick would need to recognize queries when they are run a second time and lookup the SQL in some internal cache, which would complicate the implementation).

So instead Slick compiles the query every time, unless you explicitly cache it. This makes the behavior very predictable and ultimately easier. To cache it, you need to use `Compiled` and store the result in a place that will NOT be recomputed next time you need the query. So using a `def` like `def q1 = Compiled(...)` does not make much sense, because it would compile it every time. It should be a `val` or `lazy val`. Also you probably do not want to put that val into a class you instantiate multiple times. A good place instead is a `val` in a top-level Scala singleton `object`, which is only computed once and kept for the live time of the JVM.

So in other terms, `Compiled` does nothing magical. It only allows you to trigger Slick's Scala-to-SQL compilation explicitly and return a value that contains the SQL. Importantly, this allows to trigger compilation separately from actually executing the query, which allows you to compile once, but run it multiple times.

Answer (score 10):

The *advantage* is easy to explain: Query compilation takes time, both in Slick and in the database server. If you execute the same query many times, it's faster to compile only once.

Slick needs to compile an AST with collection operations into a SQL statement. (Actually, without compiled queries you always have to *build* the AST first but compared to the compilation times this is extremely fast.)

The database server has to build an execution plan for a query. This means parsing the query, translating it to native database operations, and finding optimizations based on the data layout (e.g. which index to use). This part can be avoided even if you don't use compiled queries in Slick, simply by using bind variables, so that you always get the same SQL code for different sets of parameters. A database server keeps a cache of recently used / compiled executions plans, so as long as the SQL statement is identical, the execution plan is only a hash lookup away and doesn't need to be computed again. Slick relies on this kind of caching. There is no direct communication from Slick to the database server to reuse an old query.

As to how they are implemented, there is some additional complexity for dealing with streaming / non-streaming and compiled / applied / ad-hoc queries in the same way, but the interesting entry point is in `Compiled`:

```
implicit def function1IsCompilable[A , B <: Rep[_], P, U](implicit ashape: Shape[ColumnsShapeLevel, A, P, A], pshape: Shape[ColumnsShapeLevel, P, P, _], bexe: Executable[B, U]): Compilable[A => B, CompiledFunction[A => B, A , P, B, U]] = new Compilable[A => B, CompiledFunction[A => B, A, P, B, U]] {
  def compiled(raw: A => B, profile: BasicProfile) =
    new CompiledFunction[A => B, A, P, B, U](raw, identity[A => B], pshape.asInstanceOf[Shape[ColumnsShapeLevel, P, P, A]], profile)
}
```

This gives you an implicit `Compilable` object for every `Function`. Similar methods for arities 2 to 22 are auto-generated. Because the individual parameters only need a `Shape`, they can also be nested tuples, HLists or any custom type. (We still provide abstractions for all function arities because it's syntactically more convenient to write, say, a `Function10` than a `Function1` that takes a `Tuple10` as its argument.)

There's a method in `Shape` that only exists to support compiled functions:

```
/** Build a packed representation containing QueryParameters that can extract
  * data from the unpacked representation later.
  * This method is not available for shapes where Mixed and Unpacked are
  * different types. */
def buildParams(extract: Any => Unpacked): Packed
```

The "packed" representation built by this method can produce an AST containing `QueryParameter` nodes with the correct type. They are treated the same as other literals during compilation, except that the actual values are not known. The extractor starts as `identity` at the top level and is refined to extract record elements as required. For example, if you have a `Tuple2` parameter, the AST will end up with two `QueryParameter` nodes which know how to extract the first and second parameter of the tuple at a later point.

This later point is when the compiled query is *applied*. Executing such an `AppliedCompiledFunction` uses the pre-compiled SQL statement (or compiles it on the fly when you use it for the first time) and fills in the statement parameters by threading the argument value through the extractors.

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer . Now , I understand the utility of the use of compiled queries but I can't try them in an example .can you give me a concrete example . thanks

Comment: You can find plenty of examples here: https://github.com/slick/slick/blob/master/slick-testkit/src/main/scala/com/typesafe/slick/testkit/tests/TemplateTest.scala